# Regex to match error suppression but not PHPDoc comments

Tags: regex

I'm trying to create a regex that matches just the error suppression lines and nothing else, and especially not the PHPDoc comments.

If I try `^.*((?!\* )@.*$)` it also matches the PHPDoc lines and my negative lookahead is ignored even if the regex is ungreedy. I guess that's where the problem can be found...

I'm testing with the following code snippet:

```
<?php
  /**
  * A summary informing the user what the associated element does.
  *
  * A *description*, that can span multiple lines, to go _in-depth_ into the details of this element
  * and to provide some background information or textual references.
  *
  * @param string $myArgument With a *description* of this argument, these may also
  *    span multiple lines.
  *
  * @return void
  */
  function myFunction($myArgument)
  {
         @$error_supression
  }
```

---

P.S.:
if I try matching `^[^\*]*((?!\* )@.*$)` it matches

```
  function myFunction($myArgument)
  {
         @$error_supression
```

even though I've got a `^` for the start of the line in my regex...

---

P.P.S.:
fixed it with `^[^\*\n]*((?!\* )@.*$)`, even though it won't match a `*` before an error suppression operator, but I guess it won't appear anyway!
But still I'd love to have my original regex fixed...

Comment: Did you try with `^\s*@.*$`?

Comment: Yes, but this only works if the error supression operator is at the "beginning" of the line!

Comment: The problem didn't change! It will just match at the "beginning" of the line!

Comment: Doesn't work at all...
You could test your regex with https://regex101.com/ for instance before you post them.

Comment: Did you click the link to regex101.com that I posted? Nice that you solved it, it matches more than it should I think https://regex101.com/r/IHIbfy/1

Comment: haha, cmon, are you kidding me? That's exactly my regex!

Comment: Yes that is not what I meant. That is your regex (I posted a different one), but my point is that I am wondering if your regex is not matching more than it should.

Comment: Well, it matches better than everything else. Of course I could always improve it, but that's not the point I'm asking about. I just want my negative lookahead to work.

Comment: Feeling your comment a little agressive. Your question is missing info and your example also... That's why I made a suggestion. Add some precision if you want more help.

Comment: Ok, well, you are right. But still that would be common sense. And I just had aggression towards @Thefourthbird because I felt like he's kidding oder trolling me...and because somebody, I don't really know the user name, so it could have been somebody else, kept sending really useless regexes and deleted his comments afterwards.

Comment: OK. Please explain what exactly you want to match and what you don't want to match.

Comment: I want to match all error suppression operators (`@function(`,`@$variable`,`@somethingelse`) and everything behind them but NOT the PHPDoc comments(`* @param`). Ideally I would love to exclude @ in quotes, but that seems to be quite complicated, so it's just a tiny _nice to have_!

Comment: Then your lookahead should be placed at the beginning of the line to be able to prevent the regex to match comments. Something like `^(?!\s*\*)[^@]*(@.+)$` should work.

Comment: Did you test it on regex101.com? I did and it matches a lot. And also PHPDoc comments...

Comment: see here: https://regex101.com/r/k0sbQf/1

Comment: Didn't thought about new line chars. See [v2](https://regex101.com/r/k0sbQf/2).

Comment: I didn't think about anything, i just took your regex and executed it. Your new one found a lot more than my old one, I'll have to compare the results.

Comment: Yours finds loads of comment lines with `/** @` in the beginning!

Comment: Then `\*` in the lookahead should become `(?:\*|\\/\*\*)` as in [v3](https://regex101.com/r/k0sbQf/3). I'm pretty sure you could have figure it out.